# What is best practice to work with Liquibase across different application versions?

Tags: version-control, liquibase

I would like to know how to handle versioning of application along with Liquibase files. Let's say that I have 4 application versions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0. In 4.0, I have the following structure :

```
> - 1.0-changeset.xml
> - 2.0-changeset.xml
> - 3.0-changeset.xml
> - 4.0-changeset.xml
> - changesetMaster.xml (include all above files)
```

Respectively, version 3.0 of the application contains only 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 changeset files (without 4.0).

Now my question is: **how do I handle bug fixing in different application versions, which require database changes?**

For instance, a bug has been fixed in version 3.0. If the bug appears in 4.0 should I add changes to `3.0-changeset.xml` in 3.0 application version, and `3.0-changeset.xml` in 4.0 application version ? Or in 4.0 application version should I add it to `4.0-changeset.xml`? The same question applies to the bug which exists only in 3.0 version. Should I add then a fix to 4.0 version too ?

**Generally speaking, what is the best way to manage liquibase changeset files across different application versions?**

Answer (score 0):

Your application source code is stored in a version control system (VCS) like git. For different releases you use different branches.

You have only one liquibase changelog file that contains all database changes from the beginning of time to the current development version. This changelog is stored in your VCS along with the application source code.

When you fix a bug in the current development branch and the versions 4.0 and 3.0, you make a commit on each of these branches that contains the code changes along with a new change set in the liquibase changelog.

During a build, you check out the software and the changelog from the desired branch and build the application. During deployment, you install the new application code and run a liquibase `update` against the database.